# Prove that $p(x) = O(x^n)$ for any polynomial of degree $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't understand the proof that my book provides. [image]

I'm having trouble understanding why the equation

$$\left(\frac{b_0}{n^m} + \frac{b_1}{n^{m-1}}+\ldots\right)n^m$$

simplifies to

$$\left(b_0 + b_1+\ldots\right)n^m$$

I'd imagine that for some large number m the exponents would be small compared to their coefficients but don't see why the n's inside the parentheses are affected while the one outside isn't.

Comment: It's an inequality, and clearly when you get rid of those denominators you get something that is bigger.

Comment: It doesn't simplify. It just states $\dfrac{b_0}{n^m}\le b_0$ and so on.

Comment: nvm............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an inequality.

Since $n \geq 1$, $\frac1{n^i} \leq 1$

$$\sum_{i=0}^m \frac{b_i}{n^{m-i}}\leq \sum_{i=0}^m b_i$$